# Rename-Item renaming issue

Tags: powershell, file-rename, get-childitem

I am wrote some code and the first time it worked fine. However, I've now replaced the files with new dummy files and I'm now getting the following:

`MyTestFile.zip` is changed to `MyTestFile_zip.zip_zip.zip`
`MyTestFile.prd` is changed to `MyTestFile_prd.prd_prd.prd`

Here's the code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.prd" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '.prd','_prd.prd'}
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.zip" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '.zip','_zip.zip'}
```

Got any ideas how I can avoid this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Strange, your solution work on my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-replace` operator

- takes a *regular expression* as its first operand and
- performs *substring* matching by default.

Therefore, you must modify the regex that is the first operand for the replacement to work as intended:

```
$_.Name -replace '\.prd$','_prd.prd'
```

- `.` is escaped as `\.` to make sure that `-replace` treats it as a *literal*; without the `\`, `.` would match *any* character.
- `$` ensures that the expression is *anchored* to the *end* of the input, i.e., only matches at the end.

A more generic reformulation that covers *both* `.prd` and `.zip`:

```
$_.Name -replace '\.(prd|zip)$','_$1.$1'
```

See below for an explanation.

If we put this all together, we can get away with a single pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -File *.prd, *.zip -Recurse | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.(prd|zip)$','_$1.$1' }
```

---

Use of regular expressions allows you to process more than one extension at a time, and also allow you to reference parts of what the regular expression matched (captured) through *capture groups* (parenthesized subexpressions) that you can reference as `$1` (1st capture group, ...) in the *replacement string*

```
> @( 'example.zip', 'example.prd' ) -replace '\.(prd|zip)$','_$1.$1'
example_zip.zip
example_prd.prd
```

Note how `$1` in the replacement string refers to whatever capture group `(prd|zip)` captured, which is `zip` for the first input, and `prd` for the second.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Editor's note**:
While this answer doesn't work for the specific question at hand, because it inserts an extraneous `.`, it does show the use of `[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()` as a robust way to change a file's extension in general.</sup>

Alternatively use the .net method to change the file extension:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.prd" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.name,"_prd.prd")}
```